# Update columns using other columns of same data.table, using only their string name

Tags: r, string, data.table

I have a lot of columns that I want to update using values of other columns in the same data.table. I need to use their string names. Indeed, I have very large vector of variable names of the form:

```
cols.x <- c('name1.x', 'name2.x', 'name3.x', ...)
```

that I want to update using other columns:

```
cols.y <- c('name1.y', 'name2.y', 'name3.y', ...)
```

However, I could not find a way to make data.table understand I have also columns in the right hand side of the :=, and not the string.

Here is the working example:

```
library(data.table)

# Setting the data.table
DT <- data.table(V1.x=c(NA,c(1:5)), V2.x=c(NA,LETTERS[1:5]), V1.y=6:1, V2.y=LETTERS[1:6])

# Preparing the columns
cols.x <- c('V1.x','V2.x')
cols.y <- c('V1.y','V2.y')

# Assign cols.y to cols.x when cols.x is NA
DT[is.na(V1.x) | is.na(V2.x), cols.x := cols.y, with = F]

print(DT)

# Output
    V1.x V2.x V1.y V2.y
1:   NA  V1.y   6    A
2:    1    A    5    B
3:    2    B    4    C
4:    3    C    3    D
5:    4    D    2    E
6:    5    E    1    F

# Desired Output
    V1.x V2.x V1.y V2.y
1:    6    A    6    A
2:    1    A    5    B
3:    2    B    4    C
4:    3    C    3    D
5:    4    D    2    E
6:    5    E    1    F
```

I tried many other solution such as:

```
DT[is.na(V1.x) | is.na(V2.x), cols.x := get(cols.y)]
# or
DT[is.na(V1.x) | is.na(V2.x), cols.x := as.list(cols.y)]
```

but nothing gives me the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this solution that works

```
DT[is.na(V1.x) | is.na(V2.x), (cols.x) := DT[is.na(V1.x) | is.na(V2.x),cols.y, with = F]]
```

Comment: As of data.table 1.10.4, you can use the prepend `..` to reference vectors of variable names that were created outside of `data.table`, so the following tweek to your answer `DT[is.na(V1.x) | is.na(V2.x), (cols.x) := DT[is.na(V1.x) | is.na(V2.x), ..cols.y]]`.

Comment: Thanks ! So this is the new version of "with = FALSE" ?

Comment: it does replace some of the functionality of `with=FALSE` in some instances, but it functions similar to the reserved words like `.N` or `.grp`. It basically says look up one level for objects with given name and use these as the variables. As you saw with the previous warning `DT[i, (colvector) := val]` is another instance of the replacement of `with=FALSE`. See here for the posting on using `..` prefixes: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md for version 1.10.2